# select2: is there a way to propagate a class from an option to the item presented in the list?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

In my scenario, I'm preloading  a select with several options and I was wondering if there's any way to add a class to the li that get generated by the control so that I can change its styles. Here's the code I'm using on the server side to generate the select (ASP.NET MVC):

```
<select id="areas" name="areas" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach (var area in Model.AreasAssociadas) {
        <option value="@area.IdArea" selected="selected" @Html.Raw(area.Active ? "" : "class='disabled'")>@area.Nome</option>
    }
</select>
```

Now, I'd like to change the default UI, but only for those items that are disabled (ie, for all the items where the Active property returns false). Btw, I want to add a style so that I can get something like this:

[image]

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like there's not a property or event to handle this, I've ended up adding codes for changing the dom on the fly. not the best option, but gets the work done...